# How does Response.IsClientConnected work under the covers?

Tags: asp.net

How does Response.IsClientConnected work under the covers?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to find out is by using [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and examining the `Response.IsClientConnected` property. It allows you to decompile and anaylze .NET assemblies. It's an essential tool in the .NET developers arsenal.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Phaedrus' advice, I used Reflector to look at the code in System.Web. It looks like this property calls into native methods in webengine.dll.

This method seems to be called under IIS6: EcbIsClientConnected (http://forums.iis.net/t/1187030.aspx)

This method seems to be called under IIS7: MgdIsClientConnected

Not particularly helpful. ;-)